# How to set docker mongo data volume

Tags: mongodb, docker

I want to use Dockerizing MongoDB and store data in local volume.

But .. failed ...

It has `mongo:latest` images

```
kerydeMacBook-Pro:~ hu$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
mongo               latest              b11eedbc330f        2 weeks ago         317.4 MB
ubuntu              latest              6cc0fc2a5ee3        3 weeks ago         187.9 MB
```

I want to store the mono data in `~/data`. so ---

```
kerydeMacBook-Pro:~ hu$ docker run -p 27017:27017 -v ~/data:/data/db --name mongo -d mongo
f570073fa3104a54a54f39dbbd900a7c9f74938e2e0f3f731ec8a3140a418c43
```

But ... it not work...

> docker ps -- no daemon mongo

```
kerydeMacBook-Pro:~ hu$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

try to run "mongo" --failed

```
kerydeMacBook-Pro:~ hu$ docker exec -it f57 bash
Error response from daemon: Container f57 is not running
```

> docker inspect mongo

```
kerydeMacBook-Pro:~ hu$ docker inspect mongo
[
{
    "Id": "f570073fa3104a54a54f39dbbd900a7c9f74938e2e0f3f731ec8a3140a418c43",
    "Created": "2016-02-15T02:19:01.617824401Z",
    "Path": "/entrypoint.sh",
    "Args": [
        "mongod"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "exited",
        "Running": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "ExitCode": 100,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2016-02-15T02:19:01.74102535Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2016-02-15T02:19:01.806376434Z"
    },




"Mounts": [
        {
            "Source": "/Users/hushuming/data",
            "Destination": "/data/db",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true
        },
        {
            "Name": "365e687c4e42a510878179962bea3c7699b020c575812c6af5a1718eeaf7b57a",
            "Source": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/365e687c4e42a510878179962bea3c7699b020c575812c6af5a1718eeaf7b57a/_data",
            "Destination": "/data/configdb",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true
        }
    ],
```

**If I do not set data volume, mongo image can work!**

But, when setting data volume, it can't. Who can help me?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try and check [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)  to see what was going on when the container stopped and go in "Existed" mode.

See also if specifying the full path for the volume would help:

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 -v /home/<user>/data:/data/db  ...
```

The OP adds:

```
docker logs mongo 
exception in initAndListen: 98 
Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock 
errno:13 Permission denied 
Is a mongod instance already running?
terminating 2016-02-15T06:19:17.638+0000 
I CONTROL [initandlisten] dbexit: rc: 100
```

An errno:13 is what [issue 30](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/30) is about.

[This comment](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/30#issuecomment-94419398) adds:

> It's a file ownership/permission issue (not related to this docker image), either using boot2docker with VB or a vagrant box with VB.
>
> Nevertheless, I managed to hack the ownership, **remounting the /Users shared volume inside boot2docker to uid 999 and gid 999 (which are what mongo docker image uses)** and got it to start:

```
$ boot2docker ssh
$ sudo umount /Users
$ sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=999,gid=999 Users /Users
```

But...  mongod crashes due to filesystem type not being supported (mmap not working on vboxsf)

So the actual solution would be to try a **[DVC: Data Volume Container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/)**, because right now the [mongodb doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#fsync-on-directories) mentions:

> MongoDB requires a filesystem that supports `fsync()` on directories.
>   For example, HGFS and Virtual Box’s shared folders do not support this 
>   operation.

So:

> the mounting to OSX will not work for MongoDB because of the way that virtualbox shared folders work.

---

For a DVC (Data Volume Container), try [`docker volume create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/):

```
docker volume create mongodbdata
```

Then use it as:

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 -v mongodbdata:/data/db  ...
```

And see if that works better.

As I mention [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400740/how-to-set-docker-mongo-data-volume/35402611#comment58511054_35402611):

A `docker volume inspect mongodbdata` (see [`docker volume inspect`](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_inspect)) will give you its path (that you can then backup if you need)

Comment: run docker logs mongo ,--exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2016-02-15T06:19:17.638+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

Comment: Probably a permission issue then

Comment: @KeryHu I have edited the answer to provide a possible workaround.

Comment: @KeryHu I have edited the answer with the DVC (Data Volume Container) alternative, since you cannot mount a local folder to your container.

Comment: @VonCYes,thanks your answer,i see it just now. but running boot2docker ssh
bash: boot2docker: command not found  ,

Comment: @KeryHu don't bother with that part, it was illustrating mounting a folder with special permission was not enough. Simply create a DVC and mount it as described in the last part of the answer.

Comment: "docker volume create mongodbdata  "  .
 Do i need to care about the local path referred by "mongodbdata",and how to config it ?

Comment: @KeryHu you will configure it at runtime, on the docker run command, as mentioned in the answer. The volume will be mounted at the right `/data/db` path.

Comment: @VonCwhen i set docker volume create --name mongodbdata , Can i run " docker run --volumes-from  mongodbdata --name mongo -p 27017:27017  -d mongo "  ??,,Why i meet en error --"Error response from daemon: no such id: mongodbdata "

Comment: @KeryHu No, as mentioned in the answer it is `docker run -p 27017:27017 -v mongodbdata:/data/db  ... `: you do not create a container, you create a volume.

Comment: @VonC-yes,thanks ,mongo data volume has worked  ! But i have an question --How to copy or backup the mongodbdata volume , since it can not run "--volumes-from"

Comment: @KeryHu a `docker volume inspect mongodbdata` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_inspect/) will give you its path (that you can then backup if you need)

Answer (score 45):

Per [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/):

> Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by and used by Docker containers.

```
docker volume create mongodbdata
docker run -p 27017:27017 -v mongodbdata:/data/db mongo
```

Comment: I don't see this statement at docker docs anymore. Could you please review and update your answer?

Comment: The new URL for this statement is https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Volumes are recommend: `In addition, volumes are often a better choice than persisting data in a container’s writable layer, because a volume does not increase the size of the containers using it, and the volume’s contents exist outside the lifecycle of a given container.` Source: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: @KevinO. Are you confusing my use of the phrase "local volume" and "docker volume". As stated above, "volumes are the preferred mechanism". I think (though I have forgotten), the phrase "local volume" refers to an earlier approach before docker volumes existed. I'll updated the text of my response to not use the phrase "local volume".

Answer (score 43):

Via Docker Compose:

```
version: '2'
    services:
      mongodb:
        image: mongo:latest
        volumes:
          - ./<your-local-path>:/data/db
```

`/data/db` is the location of the data saved on the container.

`<your-local-path>` is the location on your machine AKA the host machine where the actual database journal files will be saved.

Comment: This method uses bind mounts which is not preffereable, one should use docker `volumes` instead
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 10):

For anyone running MongoDB container on Windows: as described [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/232#issuecomment-355423692), there's an issue when you mount volume from Windows host to MongoDB container using path (we call this `local volume`).

You can overcome the issue using a `Docker volume` (volume managed by Docker):

```
docker volume create mongodata
```

Or using `docker-compose` as my preference:

```yaml
version: "3.4"

services:
  ....
  
  db:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
    restart: unless-stopped
 
volumes:
  mongodata:
```

Tested on Windows 10 and it works

Comment: docker volume create mongodata

Answer (score -5):

Found a link: VirtualBox Shared Folders **are not** [supported by mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#fsync-on-directories).