# How can I create a docker volume container in specific directory?

Tags: docker

I have an SSD drive mounted at `/ssd`. I'd like to create a docker volume container for a MySQL server that will be run in a container, and have it use this SSD drive for data storage. It seems that by default, docker creates data volume containers in `/var/lib/docker`. How can I force docker to use the SSD drive for the data volume container?

Answer (score 0):

The point of containers is they're decoupled. There's not any way to segregate 'where they go' by local filesystem.

However what I do for my databases is pass through mount:

```
docker create -v /ssd:/path/to/data --name data_for_mysql <imagename> /bin/true
```

Then you can run with `--volumes-from data_for_mysql`. It will write directly on the filesystem.

Comment: Although... I just found out for mongodb, mounting from the filesystem does not work when used through boot2docker: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35402611/6309

Comment: Decoupled...from what? From the physical media? It seems like they're actually extremely tightly coupled to a single directory /var/lib/docker

Comment: The filesystem. Docker containers are supposed to be self contained, and not really care 'where they go', because that's the responsibility of the operating system. Because of how they do layering stuff, it's actually quite hard to separate out some containers from the 'common pool'. Which is why filesystem mounts exist.

Comment: Ok, regarding that specific image - I would suggest the answer is 'build your own' with a Dockerfile. It isn't particularly hard.

Comment: Is the answer that you can't create a data volume container that doesn't actually store the data in /var/lib? I ran out of disk space on AWS and have a larger volume where I would rather store the data rather than var/lib.