# How to add volumes to docker mongo container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

```
web:
  build: .
  command: python3 /app/app/__init__.py
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  links:
    - db

db:
  image: mongo:3.6.5
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`. I have a database dump in this same folder which is a collection of `json` and `bson` files. I want to avoid doing mongorestore again and again and want my flask app to take data from the dump directly as soon as I do `docker-compose` up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400740/how-to-set-docker-mongo-data-volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
volumes:
        - '/home/sa/data/db:/data/db'
```

`/home/sa/data/db` is dump files folder on host

`/data/db` is a folder in docker container.

Comment: `volumes:
        - ./june-27-dump-3/dev_datamining:/data/db`
I am using this command inside the compose file. But this is just creating some random files in my dev_datamining folder and i am not getting any data on the localhost

Comment: how is config for mongo db and how is chmod for /data/db folder in container ?

Comment: Was doing a silly syntax mistake there. Figured that out. Thanks :D