# Mongodb running on Docker is wiping the collection after restart

Tags: database, mongodb, docker, dockerfile, containers

I have to build a small application that reads data from MongoDB running on docker and uses it for further processes.

The problem is that after I close docker, the local instance of the database is also getting deleted. How can I stop it?

The `MONGODB_URI` is `mongodb://localhost:27017` and what are the attributes that I should add in the docker command to avoid it. should I avoid using localhost? `docker-compose` seems confusing to me so I use Dockerfile.

So, what exactly can be the docker run command to avoid it? is it one of these?

```
Commands: docker run -d --name mongo-on-docker -p 27017:27017 mongo
          docker run -d --name sample --link mongo-on-docker web app
```

Also to permanently save what data directory should I use?

Comment: Mount a volume do `/data/db`. This information is available on their [docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo).

Comment: it seems you don't really understand the different objects and relations for containers and Docker specifically. you should check out the difference between Dockerfile and docker-compose, as well as volumes (bind mounts and name volumes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker container are dead before quiting. For store data you should mount named volume, folder or file to the container.
In MongoDB case try:

```sh
docker run --rm -ti -v mongo_data:/data/db mongo bash
```

Where **mongo_data** is a special Docker entity, that can be mounted as a folder into container. Including in different containers at the same time.

Not new:
[How to set docker mongo data volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400740/how-to-set-docker-mongo-data-volume)